# Is Array has a node element ? Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to go through the array and find out if my array has children elements. Example any time i got array like a:

```
[
 id: 1,
 title: 'Parent',
 children : [
 {
   id: 13,
   title: 'Child'
 }
]
```

any time i got array:

```
[
 id: 1,
 title: 'Parent',
 children : [
 {
   id: 13,
   title: 'Child'
 },
 {
   id: 14,
   title: 'Child two'
 }
]
```

To explain better. The elements have their parent, child elements. What is my task? I need to find all the elements I get and put them in a array separately. So I need to extract these child elements from the array and put them in one array where all the elements are.

After looping of above array i need to get new array like:

**FROM**:

```
[
 id: 1,
 title: 'Parent',
 children : [
 {
   id: 13,
   title: 'Child'
 },
 {
   id: 14,
   title: 'Child two'
 }
]
```

**TO**

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Parent', 
 },
 {
   id: 13,
   title: 'Child'
 },
 {
   id: 14,
   title: 'Child two'
 }
]
```

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple parents and multiple children? How do you associate a particular child with a particular parent?

Comment: Very very good question! That's right. All children can have their own children. And all of them need to be push out of the array.

Comment: Your array isn't valid. It looks more like an object. Maybe you could add your code as a [mcve]?

Comment: `const recurs1 = arr => arr.reduce((f, i) => ({...f, [i.id] : i.title, ...('children' in i ? recurse1(i.children) : {})}),{});` <-- this method `recurs1` should get the desired result. Please let me know if it works & we can put this as an answer.

Comment: @Andy how is not valid ????

Comment: Arrays are lists of things. Objects are more like dictionaries that have key/value pairs. Your array isn't a list of things, it's a set of key/values, which makes it unworkable.

Comment: Thanks, @dahat12, but while I appreciate the compliments I'd much prefer you answered the question. As it is, we don't know how you associate a child with its parent. So, could you [edit] your question to add those details?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions? Is there a useful solution or a solution that you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursive way of doing it:

The outer function `collect(arr)` provides a scope for the inner recursively called function `getItems()`. Whenever a child item is found the properties `id` and `title` are assembled into a new object and pushed into the results array `res` that was defined in `collect()`.

```js
const data=[{id:1,
             title:'Parent',
             children:[{id:13,
                        title:'Child'},
                       {id:14,
                        title:'Child two',
                        children: [{id:15,
                                    title:'Grandchild'}] 
                       }]},
             {id:16,
              title:'Uncle'}
           ];
           
function collect(arr){
 const ret=[];
 function getItems(ob){
   ret.push({id:ob.id,title:ob.title});
   if (ob.children) ob.children.forEach(getItems);
 }
 arr.forEach(getItems)
 return ret
}

console.log(collect(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"title":"Parent","children":[{"id":13,"title":"Child"},{"id":14,"title":"Child two"}]}];

const flatObj = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, { id, title, children }) => ([
  ...acc,
  ...(children) ? [{ id, title }, ...flatObj(children)] : [{ id, title }]
]), []);

console.log(flatObj(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given an array of objects where an object will always have `id`, `title` and may or may not have the prop `children`, the stated/assumed objective is to transform this array into an array which only has `id` and `title` (including the children's `id`, `title`).

**Sample Code**

```
const getIdTitles = arr => (
    arr.reduce(
    (f, i) => (
        {
        ...f,
        [i.id] : i.title,
        ...(
            'children' in i
            ? getIdTitles(i.children)
            : {}
           )
      }
    ),
    {}
  )
);
```

**Approach**

- The idea is to use a recursive method
- Iterate through the given array using `reduce`
- Use `...` spread-operator to first spread contents of the aggregator `f`
- Next, add the current array element's `id` and `title`
- Then, if the current element contains `children` then recurse

**Code Snippet**

```js
const someArray = [{
 id: 1,
 title: 'Parent',
 children : [
 {
   id: 13,
   title: 'Child'
 },
 {
   id: 14,
   title: 'Child two'
 }
 ]
}];

const getIdTitles = arr => (
    arr.reduce(
    (f, i) => (
        {
        ...f,
        [i.id] : i.title,
        ...(
            'children' in i
            ? getIdTitles(i.children)
            : {}
           )
      }
    ),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(getIdTitles(someArray))
```